Connect Thunderbolt Display to Surface Studio 1

I have the following ports available on Surface Studio 1 and want to connect an Apple Thunderbolt Display 27 as a secondary monitor?



The thunderbolt cable from Thunderbolt display


Question: Is there a solution via adapters?

Lateral Approach A: Maybe connect some cables from the studio to the thunderbolt display
Lateral Approach B: Buy the newest Apple Studio Display Monitor

No adapter converts DisplayPort to Thunderbolt so the Apple display isn’t the correct external for that type of hardware.
Apple’s current Studio Display takes Thunderbolt 3 in, so that’s also a non-starter for you.
Many PC work with the above displays, just not your selection.
Select any display that accepts DisplayPort input. There adapters will help you connect things and get a signal.
